# How to create new rows in a dataframe based on another row's contents

Tags: r

Given

```
index = c(1,2,3,4,5)
codes = c("c1","c1,c2","","c3,c1","c2")
df=data.frame(index,codes)
df
  index codes
1     1    c1
2     2 c1,c2
3     3      
4     4 c3,c1
5     5    c2
```

How can I create a new df that looks like

```
df1
  index codes
1     1    c1
2     2    c1
3     2    c2
4     3      
5     4    c3
6     4    c1
7     5    c2
```

so that I can perform aggregates on the codes? The "index" of the actual data set are a series of timestamps, so I'll want to aggregate by day or hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method of Roland is quite good, provided the variable index has unique keys. You can gain some speed by working with the lists directly. Take into account that :

- in your original data frame, codes is a factor. No point in doing that, you want it to be character.
- in your original data frame, "" is used instead of NA. As the length of that one is 0, you can get in all kind of trouble later on. I'd use NA there. " " is an actual value, "" is no value at all, but you want a missing value. Hence `NA`.

So my idea would be:

The data:

```
index = c(1,2,3,4,5)
codes = c("c1","c1,c2",NA,"c3,c1","c2")
df=data.frame(index,codes,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then :

```
X <- strsplit(df$codes,",")
data.frame(
  index = rep(df$index,sapply(X,length)),
  codes = unlist(X) 
  )
```

Or, if you insist on using `""` instead of NA:

```
X <- strsplit(df$codes,",")
ll <- sapply(X,length)
X[ll==0] <- NA
data.frame(
  index = rep(df$index,pmax(1,ll)),
  codes = unlist(X) 
  )
```

Neither of both methods assume a unique key in `index`. They work perfectly well with non-unique timestamps.

Comment: @agstudy it's not even necessary here, provided you change the "" value to NA in the vector code.

Comment: yes I had to do that if my solution. it is neraly the same , I just use `scan(textConnection(df$codes),what='character',sep=',')` ( maybe faster than strsplit)

Comment: To change the "" to missing values you can do something like : `df$codes[nchar(df$codes)==0] <- NA_character_`

Comment: thanks for the answers. I'll poke with them. It is not a good assumption that my "index" values are unique - they are timestamps which could be identical. My bad for not making a sample with that condition. 

oh, and NA is perfectly fine - I get "" in the extract, but easy enough to convert

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the string (using `strsplit`) and then combine the resulting list with the data.frame.

The following relies on the assumption that codes are unique in each row. If you have many codes in some rows and only few in others, this might waste a lot of RAM and it might be better to loop.

```
#to avoid character(0), which would be omitted in rbind
levels(df$codes)[levels(df$codes)==""] <- " "

#rbind fills each row by propagating the values to the "empty" columns for each row
df2 <- cbind(df, do.call(rbind,strsplit(as.character(df$codes),",")))[,-2]

library(reshape2)
df2 <- melt(df2, id="index")[-2]
#here the assumtion is needed
df2 <- df2[!duplicated(df2),]
df2[order(df2[,1], df2[,2]),]

#  index value
#1     1    c1
#2     2    c1
#7     2    c2
#3     3      
#9     4    c1
#4     4    c3
#5     5    c2
```

Comment: Or the more obtuse (!) `do.call( rbind , apply( df , 1 , function(x) cbind( x[1] , unlist( strsplit( x[2] , split = "," ) ) ) ) )` (but doesn't rely on unique codes, just recycling rules). And assumes you have converted the empty `factor` level to `" "` as you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative using "data.table". The sample data includes `NA` instead of a blank space and includes duplicated index values:

```
index = c(1,2,3,2,4,5)
codes = c("c1","c1,c2",NA,"c3,c1","c2","c3")
df = data.frame(index,codes,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(data.table)
## We could create the data.table directly, but I'm 
## assuming you already have a data.frame ready to work with
DT <- data.table(df)  
DT[, list(codes = unlist(strsplit(codes, ","))), by = "index"]
#    index codes
# 1:     1    c1
# 2:     2    c1
# 3:     2    c2
# 4:     2    c3
# 5:     2    c1
# 6:     3    NA
# 7:     4    c2
# 8:     5    c3
```